# Spring Profile conditional prop files multiple environment

Tags: spring, maven, spring-profiles

I have a question, with Spring Profiles. I understand the reason for not using maven profiles because each environment would require another artifact. That makes since. I modified my code to use Spring Profile but the problem I have with Spring Profiles is that it requires you to have a database.property file for each environment, on the server. I have this setup, same setup everyone has seen a hundred times.

```
src
- main
- resources
   -conf
     myapp.properties
   -env
      dev.db.properties
      test.db.properties
      prod.db.properties
```

The problem I think with this setup is that, each server would have all the files in the env dir (i.e. dev would have prod.db.properties and test.db.properties files on its server). Is there a way to only copy the files that are needed during the build of maven without using profiles? I haven't been able to figure out a way. If that is the case, then this would seem like a reason to use maven profiles. I may have missed something. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a chicken and egg problem to me. If you want your artifact to work on all these 3 environments you need to ship the 3 configurations. Not doing so would lead to the same issue you mentioned originally. It's generally a bad practice to build an artifact with certain coordinates differently according to a profile.

If you do not want to ship the configuration in the artifact itself, you could externalize the definition either through the use of system property or by locating a properties file at a defined place (that you could override for convenience).

Comment: Decided to externalize property in a common directory across all environments. One artifact multiple environments achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You should first point out what your application really is: If you are running "an application in different environments" or if you are running "different applications in their own propritary environments". This are two slightly different concepts:

- If you are running an application in different environments its better to put all property files into your jar. Bring it into mind by imagine that you buy a new SUV; you first drive it on a test track, then after on ordinary highways before going offroad to finally enjoy its offroad capabilities. You always use one and the same car in different environments with all its capabilities and driving characteristics. In each environment the car adapts its behaviour and driving characteristics. If you use one application to drive it through different environment, so use the first approach to build all environment-characteristics into one jar.
- On the other hand you can also use slightly different cars in different environments. So if you need different cars with its own special driving characteristics for different environments, maybe 4WD or special flood ligths because you are driving by night, you should take the second approach. Back to application: If you need different applications with far different characteristics in different production environments its better to build each application only with the properties it really needs.

Finally you can also merge the two approaches:

- my-fun-application-foo.jar for customer foo with properties for test, integration and production environment.
- my-fun-application-2047.jar for customer 2047 with properties for test, pre-integration, integration, pre-production and production environment.

Now you should get also an understanding why you shouldn't using profiles for building an application with different flavours.